# Can and Could Usage differences

Tags: modal-verbs

> 1). He was a popular singer back in the 90's. But I'm sure that he **couldn’t** fill a concert hall now.
>
> 2). He was a popular singer back in the 90's. But I'm sure that he **can’t** fill a concert hall now.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences? I know could is used for hypothetical cases. But what is the possible hypothetical case in the sentence1?

Answer (score 1):

> But what is the possible hypothetical case in the sentence1?

The hypothetical case in 1 is *if he held a concert*.

Sentence 2 assumes that he is in fact planning to hold a concert, or has recently tried and failed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

- Could (have the potential)
- Can (have the ability)

> 1. Couldn’t fill a concert hall (lack potential of filling a concert hall)

> 2. Can't fill a concert hall (lack ability to fill a concert hall)

If 'couldn’t' is the past tense of 'can', then it means the same as #2

Answer (score 0):

*He can't fill a concert hall* is an actual observation: either he has tried to, and it's been half empty, or he's used smaller venues and they have been adequate.

*He couldn't fill a concert hall* implies that it hasn't been tried: it's a hypothetical, and if he tried to, he would not succeed.