# Modal verbs Can and Could differences

Tags: modal-verbs

> 1). No one **can** fool me.
>
> 2). No one **could** fool me.

What is the difference in meaning between these two sentences?

Comment: This is easily findable on the web. You are supposed to make an effort on your own and then ask.

Comment: Sorry I have been trying very hard for a long time. I have even posted many questions related to this can-could. But I being able to underatand that particular answer. For new sentences , it’s new again. So could you please explain to me

Comment: can versus could https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&safe=active&biw=970&bih=386&sxsrf=ALeKk03Q1qGPCAE6g83vrkOG64U1PPvc3Q%3A1593693199529&ei=D9T9Xqz2H-iLytMP_ZGx2As&q=can+versus+could&oq=can+versus+could&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzICCAAyCAgAEBYQChAeMgYIABAWEB4yCAgAEBYQChAeOgUIABCRAjoECAAQQzoFCAAQgwE6BQgAELEDOgQIIxAnOggIABCxAxCRAjoFCCEQqwI6BAgAEApQouJqWKqDa2CQhmtoA3AAeAGAAZgBiAH9C5IBBDE2LjOYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwjsuafoya7qAhXohXIEHf1IDLsQ4dUDCAw&uact=5

Answer (score 0):

From my answer to a [similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/252552/can-and-could-usage-differences)

Can = have the ability to

Could = have the potential of

> No one can fool me. (no one has the ability to fool me)

> No one could fool me. (no one has the potential of fooling me)

Comment: "Ability" and "potential" are more or less synonyms.

Comment: have potential means you may not have the ability now, but possible to have it in the future